# How to fix this issue with flask along with session management?

Tags: python, flask

I am getting an error which says as below when I am working with this along with session management.

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'Employee_Name'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\intern\Employee_Management_system-master\app1.py", line 130, in admin_personaldetails
Employee_Name = userDetails['Employee_Name']

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 431, in __getitem__
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)

werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'Employee_Name'
```

HTML:

```
       <form action="details" method="POST">
         Employee_Name <input type="text" name="Employee_Name"/> 
         Employee_ID <input type="text" name="Employee_ID"/> 

         <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"/>     
        </form>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/details', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_personaldetails():
    if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET':
       userDetails = request.form
       if 'Employee_ID' in session:  
          Employee_ID = session['Employee_ID']
       if Employee_ID=='Admin':
          userDetails=request.form
          Employee_Name = userDetails['Employee_Name']
          Employee_ID = userDetails['Employee_ID']
          cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
          cur.execute("INSERT INTO Employee(Employee_Name, Employee_ID)      VALUES(%s, %s)",(Employee_Name, Employee_ID))
          mysql.connection.commit()
          cur.close()
          return render_template('details.html', Details = Details)
      else:
          return "<h1>No Admin rights</h1>"
 return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of your error?

Comment: I dont think it will be posted as comment.. You have to update your question.

Comment: Can you format it properly its difficult to read.

Comment: How is your userDetails dictionary populated in app1.py

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation  It is a empty form being called from html template.

Comment: Have you tried printing  request.form['Employee_Name'] and request.form['Empliyee_Id'] or whole request.form object in your python code and see if it is printing as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.form` is a Multidict which is immutable so you can try fetching complete data using `to_dict()` method.

Code:-

```
@app.route("/path", methods=["POST"])
def handle_post_request():
      if request.method == "POST": 
          data = request.form.to_dict()
          # ... do something with data ...
 return " Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method is Post, you can access to your data like below:

```
request.form['Employee_Name']
```

If the method is GET, you can access to your data like below:

```
request.args.get('Employee_Name', '')
```

So you need to replace

```
if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET':
```

By

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Edit:
Also, you need to redirect user after save the data received from the post request and replace Employee_Name by employee_name and Employee_ID by employee_id in the html and python files.

Your code will be similar to this:

```
@app.route('/details', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_personaldetails():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       userDetails = request.form
       if 'Employee_ID' in session:  
          Employee_ID = session['Employee_ID']
       else:
          Employee_ID = ""
       if Employee_ID=='Admin':
          userDetails=request.form
          Employee_Name = userDetails['employee_name']
          Employee_ID = userDetails['employee_id']
          cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
          cur.execute("INSERT INTO Employee(Employee_Name, Employee_ID)
  VALUES(%s, %s)",(Employee_Name, Employee_ID))
          mysql.connection.commit()
          cur.close()
          return redirect('/details?success=1')
      else:
          return redirect('/details?success=0')
 success = int(request.args.get('success', -100))
 if suucess == 0:
       return "<h1>No Admin rights</h1>"
 return render_template('details.html')
```

Edit: Another solution to read data:

```
userDetails=request.form
Employee_Name = ""
Employee_ID = ""
for item in userDetails:
  if item.upper() == "EMPLOYEE_NAME":
      Employee_Name = userDetails[item]
  if item.upper() == "EMPLOYEE_ID":
      Employee_ID = userDetails[item]
```

Comment: python read Employee_Name as Employee_name. So you need to replace Employee_Name by employee_name to avoid this error.

Comment: My code had Employee_Name every where even in database, html, template I never changed it

Comment: I added another solution.